# Можно ли передавать в промис ассинхронную функцию?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Можно ли использовать async при работе с промисами? То есть функцию которая передается в промис  сделать ассинхронной? Чтобы внутри нее использовать await. То есть будет ли корректно после этого работать промис?

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  let a = await someFunc();
          resolve(a);
})
```

Comment: Можно. (+10 символов чтобы оставить комментарий)

Comment: Промис сделан специально для работы с асинхронностями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут главное, где и когда вы вызовете колбэк `resolve`. Вы можете не только использовать асинхронную функцию, вы можете передавать `resolve` по любой цепочке колбэков и даже разрешать `resolve` с другим промисом — всё будет автоматически обработано:

```js
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  let a = await Promise.resolve(42);
  setTimeout(() => resolve(Promise.resolve(a)));
}).then(console.log); // 42
```